# unpredictable output while converting binary to decimal numbers

Tags: java, binary, decimal

unpredictable output while converting binary to decimal numbers
.can anybody help

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    char c[];
    String s=scanner.nextLine();
    c=s.toCharArray();
    int n=0;
    int real=0;
    int temp=0;
    System.out.println(c.length);
    for(int i=(c.length-1);i>=0;i--)
    {
        temp=(int)Math.pow(2,i);
        n=c[i]*temp;
        System.out.println(c[i]+":"+(int)Math.pow(2,i)+":"+temp+":"+n);
        real=real+n;
        System.out.println(real);
    }
    System.out.println("hello , its me aditya and your value is "+ real);
}


1111
4
1:8:8:392
392
1:4:4:196
588
1:2:2:98
686
1:1:1:49
735
hello , its me aditya and your value is 735
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing c[i] by (c[i] - ‘0’). I’m typing on my phone so that isn’t quite right. Basically the problem is you’re using the characters 0 and 1 rather than the integers they represent.

Comment: tried just ,but of no use

Comment: I think your powers might be wrong too. I think you need c.length - 1 - i in there somewhere.

Comment: I am printing the values of c[i] and math.pow also. Its correct.u can check the comments attached. But when they get multiplied the answer is different n unpredicted.

Comment: Printing c[i] doesn’t help because it it’s displaying the char, not the int it gets converted to when you multiply. Try printing ((int) c[i]) instead

Comment: `n=c[i]*temp;` You are multiplying ASCII values, not 0 or 1.

Comment: So how it can be done.

Comment: @user8623671 trivially, `n = (c[i] - '0') * temp;`. But this is an overly complicated approach anyway

Comment: @AndyTurner I think the power should be Math.pow(2, c.length - 1 - i) too

Comment: Ya. The code got executed. Thanks a ton. By the way,what's the logic behind this.

Comment: Power code is correct, the code is getting executed. But what was previous multiplication error and your logic?

Comment: Try it with 1011.

Comment: 1011 is 13 in code. What can be done

Comment: Use the power I suggested half an hour ago!

Comment: Ya. It worked fine. Can you tell me where i was going wrong

Comment: Not easily as I’m on my mobile. I’ll answer properly when I get in if somebody hasn’t already explained it.

Comment: There is no need to use pow. Process the string in order (not reverse order, as here), using `real = 2*real + (c[i] - '0');`